Cohomology ring of $S^2 \times S^2$ and $P2\#\bar{P2}$ are not isomorphic.
I want to see an algebraic proof for the fact that cohomology rings $H^*(S^2\times S^2; R)$ and $H^*(\mathrm{P}2\#\bar{\mathrm{P}2}; R)$ are not isomorphic if $2^{-1}\notin R$.
The algebras are :

$H^*(S^2\times S^2; R)=\frac{R[x,y]}{<x^2,y^2>} , |x|=|y|=2$
$H^*(\mathrm{P}2\#\bar{\mathrm{P}2}; R)= \frac{R[x,y]}{<x^2+y^2,xy>}, |x|=|y|=2 $

It is an easy fact to check that if $2^{-1}\in R$ then we can make a linear change of the basis of $1)$ as $a=\frac{x+y}{2},b=\frac{x-y}{2}$ to get a presentation similar to $2)$ together with $<a^2+b^2,ab> \cong <x^2,y^2>$.
Another example: When the given base ring is $\mathrm{Z}_2$. It's easy to see there are no such two elements in $1)$ which is a basis and has the following relations:
$a,b$ has the following possibilities:
\begin{align}
a=x+y,b=x+y\\
a=x,b=x+y\\
a=x,b=y
\end{align}
and all its mirrors are the rest possibilities and none of the combinations provides us with the required relation together with being basis.
But I couldn't figure out the idea of 1) being not isomorphic to 2) for general $R$ if $2^{-1}\notin R$.

It suffices to show that there is no choice of basis for $H^1(\mathbb{P}^2 \# \overline{\mathbb{P}}^2)$, say $x' = ax + by$ and $y' = cx + dy$, such that $x'^2 = y'^2 = 0$. Since $x^2 + y^2 = xy = 0$ and $x^2 = -y^2$ is a basis of $H^2$, $a^2 = b^2$, $c^2 = d^2$. Since $x', y'$ form a basis, $(ad - bc)^2 = 2(a^2c^2 - abcd)$ is a unit, which implies $2$ is a unit.
